# How to change the port for the SAP Virtual Default Host (SICF) configuration?

Tags: https, sap, web-services

I am unable to test services in transaction SICF in my SAP system because I have enabled HTTPS (on port 443) and removed the HTTP port.

SICF uses the Virtual Default Host. How can I change the properties of this to make it use the HTTPS connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I had to change the service parameter **icm/server_port_0** to be the main port I wanted to use (i.e. HTTPS 443).

This isn't a nice solution, but it works and I haven't found any solution documented by SAP-AG.